# Issue with storing error at each iteration on Matlab - "unrecognized variable"

Tags: matlab, while-loop, iteration

I've written a modified Newton's method code, and I'm looking to plot the error at each iteration vs the iteration, but after my code runs Matlab does not recognize my error function or the iterations.

```
function[x,k,e] = mynewton(x0,tol)

f = @(x) (x-1).^5*exp(x);
df = @(x) 5*(x-1).^4*exp(x)+(x-1).^5*exp(x);
kMax = 200;

format long
x=x0;
y=f(x);
e = [];
k = 0;
disp('          k                    x                  error')
while abs(y) > tol && k < kMax
    k=k+1;
    x = x - f(x)/df(x);
    y = f(x);
    e_k = abs(x-1);
    e(k) = e_k;
    disp([k    x     e_k])
end
end
```

The output will be 3 columns showing k, x, and e_k at each step, but it won't store these values properly into a vector. Instead, it shows

```
>> k
Unrecognized function or variable 'k'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions are very appreciated!!

Comment: How do you call the function? You need to collect the output variables when you call it.

Comment: Read about [scopes of variables](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/485576-what-are-variable-scopes)

Comment: Could you rephrase please? I tried to first initialize an empty vector for the error, and while the loop was running I stored the kth error in the kth position in this vector at each step.

Comment: I don't quite understand how scopes of variables applies to what I'm doing here, or how to collect my output variables when I call my function.

Comment: Let’s start with basics then. How do you run this code?

Comment: I run it with the line modnewton(0,1e-16).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your function as:

```
[x, k, e] = mynewton( x0, tol);
```

After this call, you can enter k at command window and see its value.

Comment: I feel very silly .... thank you for answering my very novice question. :-)